# Using LINQ Datarow -> string instead of Datarow -> String[] -> String,

Tags: linq

I want to get a particular datacoulmn values into string by appending each row values.

I have a below code which will return into string array, and then i use foreach to append each string to one string

```
string[] strs = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<string>("name")).ToArray<string>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string str in strs)
{
   sb.Append(str);
}
```

can this be replaced into LINQ query which will return result in string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) to join these together directly, which also eliminates the need to create the temporary array:

```
var result = string.Join("", ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<string>("name")));
```